# background image to full height and width using css or jquery

Tags: css, background-image

I want the background image for my home div only which is visible only for desktops and tablets(landscape). I could adjust them with CSS media query.

But my background image is not fitting to full height.

here is my pluner code. http://plnkr.co/edit/HzlZdqvprkhzO1edqNKK?p=preview

my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log($('.home').height());
});
```

is also returning null.

What is the best way to solve this.

Comment: Try `background-size: auto 100%;`

Comment: I missed an important point. I am using angularjs and ui-router and loading the image from home.tpl.html its not working. When i  load it from index.html it works perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

addi this code to youre image, and you wil l have your result without jquery:

```
background: url(http://www.pulsarwallpapers.com/data/media/3/Alien%20Ink%202560X1600%20Abstract%20Background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: cover;
height: 400px;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

the secret is using background-size: cover and then set the background as fixed with height and width 100%

Comment: You could delete the browser-prefixes from the code and mention them in the explanation as they may change in the future.

Comment: remember to select the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

console.log($('.home').height()); is returning null as you have not set height attribute for home div.

set height attribute and then you can use it or do Nick told background-size: auto 100%;

Comment: If you look into my plunker i have set the height to 100%; I want the height of the image to fit window height

Answer (score 0):

use  `background-size` property of css

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: nope. My height is not update. I made this code in plunker. I want the height to be 100%

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/fynbc5uv/ 
You said you didn't want to set height, the only workaround for this is setting the background-image on the body.
CSS:

```
body{height:100%;
   background: url(http://www.pulsarwallpapers.com/data/media/3/Alien%20Ink%202560X1600%20Abstract%20Background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```